# convert a uint8_t to an string of hex digits in C++

Tags: c++, c

I got the following code which I don't understand completely. I want to do the same thing but without changing the endianess. Can someone explain me how this code works and how I can rewrite it, so that the endianess doesn't get changed?

```
// Convert N little-endian 32 integers in FROM into TO as string of hex digits.
static uint8_t*
swap32_to_ascii(const uint8_t* from, uint8_t* to, int n)
{
  hydb_assert((n & 3) == 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      uint8_t ch = from[i ^ 3];
      *to++ = tohex(ch >> 4);
      *to++ = tohex(ch & 0xf);
    }

  return to;
}

// Convert a nibble NIB to a hex digit.
static int
tohex(int nib)
{
  if (nib < 10)
    return '0' + nib;
  else
    return 'a' + nib - 10;
}
```

Comment: No time for a full answer, but just `uint8_t ch = from[i];` will switch to big-endian.

Comment: Also `tohex` is naively written. It should be `static char tohex (uint8_t nibble) { return "0123456789ABCDEF"[nibble]; }`. No need for branches and arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is the `ch = from[i ^ 3]` line: this reverts last two bits of the index, counting backward from 3 to 0.
So index will be `3`,`2`,`1`,`0`,`7`,`6`,`5`,`4`…

As suggested by **Ken Y-N** using `ch = from[i]` is enough to swap the endianess.

In you code the *null terminator* of the result string is not set, so you need to add `*to = '\0';` before return.

As *defensive programming*, in `tohex()` function please be sure to limit `nib` to 4 bit, using `(nib & 0xf)` on the last line.